# Terraform timeout issue on local system

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, terraform, timeout

So I'm new to Terraform and trying to learn it, with some great difficultly. I run into a timeout issue on running certain things into Kubernetes that is hosted locally.

## Setup

Running on Windows 10

Running Docker for Windows with Kubernetes cluster enabled

Running WSL2 Ununtu 20 on Windows

Installed Terraform and able to access kubectl affecting the cluster

## Coding

I'm following the coding example set up from this website:

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/configuring-a-kind-cluster-with-nginx-ingress-using-terraform-and-helm

But with a modification, in that in the `demo.sh` I'm running the steps manually and the `kubectl` file they are reference, I've turned that into a Terraform file as this is how I would do deployments in the future. Also I've had to comment out the `provisioner "local-exec"` as the `kubectl` commands outright fails in Terraform.

### Code file

```
resource "kubernetes_pod" "foo-app" {
  depends_on = [helm_release.ingress_nginx]
  metadata {
    name      = "foo-app"
    namespace = var.ingress_nginx_namespace
    labels    = {
      app = "foo"
    }
  }
  spec {
    container {
      name  = "foo-app"
      image = "hashicorp/http-eco:0.2.3"
      args  = ["-text=foo"]
    }
  }
}
resource "kubernetes_pod" "bar-app" {
  depends_on = [helm_release.ingress_nginx]
  metadata {
    name      = "bar-app"
    namespace = var.ingress_nginx_namespace
    labels    = {
      app = "bar"
    }
  }
  spec {
    container {
      name  = "bar-app"
      image = "hashicorp/http-eco:0.2.3"
      args  = ["-text=bar"]
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "foo-service" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_pod.foo-app]
  metadata {
    name = "foo-service"
    namespace = var.ingress_nginx_namespace
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "foo"
    }
    port {
      port = 5678
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "bar-service" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_pod.bar-app]
  metadata {
    name = "bar-service"
    namespace = var.ingress_nginx_namespace
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "bar"
    }
    port {
      port = 5678
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "example-ingress" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_service.foo-service, kubernetes_service.bar-service]
  metadata {
    name = "example-ingress"
    namespace = var.ingress_nginx_namespace
  }
  spec {
    rule {
      host = "172.21.220.84"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/foo"
          backend {
            service_name = "foo-service"
            service_port = 5678
          }
        }
        path {
          path = "/var"
          backend {
            service_name = "bar-service"
            service_port = 5678
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## The problem

I run into 2 problems, first the pods cannot fine the name space, through it has been built, `kubectl` shows it as a valid namespace as well.

But the main problem I have is time outs. This happens on different elements all together, depending on the example. In trying to deploy the pods to the local cluster I get a 5 minute time out with this as the output after 5 minutes:

```
╷
│ Error: context deadline exceeded
│
│   with kubernetes_pod.foo-app,
│   on services.tf line 1, in resource "kubernetes_pod" "foo-app":
│    1: resource "kubernetes_pod" "foo-app" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: context deadline exceeded
│
│   with kubernetes_pod.bar-app,
│   on services.tf line 18, in resource "kubernetes_pod" "bar-app":
│   18: resource "kubernetes_pod" "bar-app" {
```

This will happen for several kinds of things, I have this problem with pods, deployments, and ingresses. This is very frustrating and I would like to know is there a particular setting I'm needing to do or am I doing something wrong with my set up?

Thanks!

Edit #1:
So I repeated this on an Ubuntu VM with MiniKube install getting the same behavior. I copied the scripts, got Terraformed installed, Minikube installed confirmed its all up and running, yet I'm getting the same behavior on there as well. I'm wondering if this is an issue with Kubernetes and Terraform?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Kubernetes in particular to be confident in an answer here, but I've seen lots of cases of folks using Terraform on Windows running into problems with software firewalls that interfere with the provider plugins' ability to access remote services. Could that be the case for you? By which I mean, do you have something filtering your outgoing requests that might be allowing `kubectl` to succeed but blocking Terraform's Kubernetes provider?

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks for letting me know about the windows and terraform issue. Something very good for me to keep in mind. I made an edit to my post in that I was able to repeat the same behavior on an Ubuntu VM with MiniKube installed on there.